# Piece of code work in iOS 6 but doesn't in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, rotation, orientation

The problem is I have a simple view animation in a table view cell, but when i run in iPhone 6 simulator works perfectly, but when i run in iPhone 5 simulator doesn't work. Also, the rotate orientation doesn't work in iOS 5 but in iOS 6 works. I've verified that the methods are not deprecated. I check everything but nothing gonna change.

Indeed, everything works fine in iOS 6 but doesn't work in iOS 5, but doesn't crash, only doesn't work.

Edit with code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"HideRow" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; 
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: In fact is not necesary, because when i debug it the breakpoint pass over the code but do not anything. Just doesn't work!!!

Comment: We really can't do much without code. Try cleaning your build folder and cleaning the project itself, also reset the simulator. If nothing of this helps, then we need some code.

Comment: Ok for example, i have this code for animation: 
[UIView beginAnimations:@"HideRow" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        
[UIView commitAnimations];

When i debug it the break point pass over the code lines, but doesn't excute them, also the rotate methods for iOS 5 doesn't work in iOS5 but in iOS 6 works perfectly!

Comment: Can you please put that in your original post. It is really hard to read right now.

Comment: I cant, i have less than 10 reputation

Comment: @user1769792 I still can't believe the irony, but I actually ran into this exact same situation... I am fixing it now...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I really doubt you are supporting iOS 3.x, so just change to [animation blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html) already. Replace your code with this:</strike>

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
}];
```

**NOTE:** Also note the simulator isn't your ideal testing environment. Try running the app on a device running iOS 5.

---

OK, yesterday, I got the exact same "symptoms" that you explained. I had some animation code that was skipped in iOS 5, but worked in iOS 6. As expected, there is nothing wrong with my code, and neither yours... The problem is **when** we are executing it.

In my case, and pretty sure your case is similar, I am doing it in the `viewDidLoad` of a view controller that gets loaded as soon as the app launches. So, a very easy fix was to wrap it with some GDC magic:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.65f
                     animations:^{
                         splashView.frame = CGRectOffset(splashView.frame, 0, splashView.bounds.size.height);
                     }];
});
```

Comment: I've already tried... doesn't work!! Only in iOS 6 device and iOS 6 simulator!